# Why modem driver is loaded and used from my linux machine in order to communicate with Arduino?

Tags: usb

Once I plugin an arduino to my linux machine the following response is retrieved (via `dmesg`):

```
[ 7250.906241] perf: interrupt took too long (2504 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79750
[ 9517.599165] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 9517.749504] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=0043, bcdDevice= 0.01
[ 9517.749510] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=220
[ 9517.749513] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Arduino (www.arduino.cc)
[ 9517.749516] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 7533131313335170A061
[ 9517.780753] cdc_acm 1-3:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[ 9517.781046] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[ 9517.781047] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
```

The last line from dmesg caught my attention:

```
[ 9517.781047] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
```

Also as far as I remember in order to communicate with arduino my user needs to be into `dialout` group. Does that mean that a modem communication protocol is used in order to communicate from/to arduino in order to communicate via USB?

Comment: linux questions belong at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions , not here

Comment: @jsotola I disagree. While the answer is in the linux domain, the question in and of itself asks whether there is "some modem protocol" happening between PC and Arduino.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to that is one of history.

There was a time when the main purpose of the serial port (RS-232/UART) was to "dial out"; i.e. it had a serial connection to a modem, fax machine or a mainframe attached. Whatever it was, the primary function was to provide a data connection to the outer world, possibly incurring charges on a phone line. So, it is the other way round than you guessed: The computer communicated with the modem using a serial protocol named RS-232 or UART.

Therefore, all serial ports have been secured to not allow access, except for the user group "dialout". This has been retained as default, even for emulated and virtual serial ports -- like, for example, serial port over USB.

Comment: So if I want my arduino to emulate a modem would the arduino's (Arduino UNO) typical out of the box USB communication be considered one that also modems use as well?

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas Yes. A "serial connection" is basically just a bidirectional channel to send and receive bytes. What those bytes mean is up to the programs at either end and it is irrelevant whether this connection is a classic serial port, an emulated Serial-over-USB port or anything else. All your modem dialer program needs to know is "the modem is on serial port /dev/ttyS0". The dialer just sends a series of "AT commands" onto the serial line, waits for the modem to connect and acknowledge, then assumes that the same serial line is now connected through to its destination.